# Setting Python script tool parameter Type based on another parameter Value?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-script-tool, parameters, tool-validation

In my script tool case, I've used the validation tool to make parameter[4] enabled only if parameter[3] equal a certain value, but i need to make this parameter[4] required only if enabled. the problem is that when i set it's type to "required" and i try to execute  the script it asks me to set a value for parameter[4] even if it stayed disabled!

Is There any solution to make it Required only if it's enabled?

Comment: Could you set a value into parameter[4] yourself when its disabled to get past validation? And inside the script handle (ignore) that value?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best bet would be to use a [python toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-python-toolboxes.htm) instead of importing the script into an existing toolbox. Then using a conditional statement to control the parameterType of parameter 4.

However I'm not sure that this is possible. You are essentially trying to update the number of inputs in an ESRI derived GUI in realtime using user selected inputs.